# Best practice in image size and resolution?

Tags: flutter

I have an App that I built with Flutter and it displays the image on the full page (body). I wanted to optimize the images before I release it to the app store, so i figured i should resize the images to their proper resolutions.

What is the recommended image size and resolution for the use-case I described above? Is a 600px by 900px image overkill for a full-page image display for an App who's primary target are mobile devices?

Comment: this is for ios right? Also I don't get what images you are trying to optimize. Is it the images being shown to the user in your app or your app icon?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I will update the post.

Answer (score 3):

I was an android dev before being a flutter dev before. In android, it is recommended to use vector drawables which are basically svgs. This should also be the same for ios and flutter. The other way to optimize images for the app to display images across multiple devices is to make separate image resolutions for each screen size. The best way to optimize images for flutter would be to use multiple image resolutions to support many different devices. It wouldn't be advisable to use svgs in flutter because the flutter's graphics engine called skia doesn't natively support it. You can still use a plugin called flutter_svg but I think that this solution would be better: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-images . You can easily minimize your app size by building your app and by not using the debug version of your app. Good Luck!